# ISNumber Search with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

sorry if this has been answered before. I looked around but still couldn't get my head around it..

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CAR"",B2)),524338)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is having the search match two criteria.
first one would be if the cell has "car" it'll output 524338. However I have another column which shows either "Domestic" or "international".

so if cell a1 has "car" and cell b1 has "domestic" it'll output 524338

but if cell a1 has "car" and cell b1 has "international" it'll output 524340

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=IF(AND(B1="domestic",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("car",A1))),524338,IF(AND(B1="international",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("car",A1))),524340,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to know! If it works then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to mark the thread as solved.

Comment: Will do when im able to test! :)

Comment: Oh! Its okay. I thought you already tested.